# Filter datefield + 5 years

Tags: forms, date, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I am using AX2012, and I want to make a change to the form: Sales Orders -> Backorder Lines. This form currently has a filter: "Backorder date:" which displays the current date. I want to adjust this date field, so that it shows me the current date + 5 years.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the interaction class `SalesLineBackOrderListPageInteraction` of the listpage, there in method `initializing` the value of the field gets set.